# Which definition for the limit of a sequence is correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So Wikipedia (and some other sources) state that the definition for a limit of sequence is:

$$ \forall \varepsilon > 0  \quad \exists N: n \geq N \implies |s_n - s | < \varepsilon  $$

My textbook (Elementary Analysis by Ross, 2nd ed.) states that the definition is this:

$$ \forall \varepsilon > 0  \quad \exists N: n > N \implies |s_n - s | < \varepsilon  $$

The only difference being $n \geq N$ versus $ n > N$. My question is how these two are equivalent? It seems to me that the definition Ross provides is a bit "stronger".

Perhaps I'm just being overly pedantic here, but I'm coming across some proofs that utilize the fact that we can set $n = N$, whereas with the book definition this is not true. How does one reconcile this apparent contradiction?

Thanks.

Comment: Any sequence that satisfies the Ross definition with $N$ as a "witness" also satisfies the Wikipedia definition with $N+1$ as a "witness."  But since we're just talking about an existential statement, it doesn't matter that the two definitions may use different witnesses.

Comment: No, the two definitions are equivalent.  If there exists $N$ such that $~\forall n > N, \cdots~$ then there exists $~(N+1)~$ such that $~\forall n \geq (N+1), \cdots.$

Comment: Keep in mind, the definition says "... there exists $N$ ...". It does not say "... there exists **a unique** $N$ ...". So if you had a valid proof with some particular formula for $N$ (expressed in terms of $\epsilon$), you could just as easily add $1$ to the formula and the proof would still be valid.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yep, that was definitely the mistake in my thinking. Thanks for helping me clear that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both equivalent.

Let $(s_n)$ be a converging sequence with limit $s$.
It's quite obvious that the first definition implies the second definition.
So we only need to show that the second definition implies the first definition: So let $\epsilon > 0$. By the second definition there exists a $N \in \mathbb N$, such that $\left| s_n - s \right| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$. Now simply set $M = N + 1$. Then
$$ \left| s_n - s \right| < \epsilon \quad \text{for all } n \geq M$$
must hold, which is exactly the first definition.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I think I made the mistake of considering the $N$ in the first definition as the same $N$ in the second one. But taking it instead as $M = N + 1$ makes the equivalence much clearer. Thanks for the help.